# Quoting someones comment in own answer

Tags: discussion, comments, answers

I have answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839057/httpservletresponse-encoding-issue/12839184#12839184). My answer had links to valuable information in context of the problem, but the conclusion was useless (striked through in my answer). Another user gave correct solution to the problem in question, in the comment to the answer.

I decided to quote his comment, so my answer would be more likely upvoted. (I could say also: to make my answer complete and more informational; but to be honest, in the end it is because of the reputation :) )

Although I quoted it, because of the reputation issue, I'm not sure how ethical it is. On the other hand, reputation is just a mechanism for getting quality answers to clearly stated practical questions, in short for the site to have the qualitiy and valuable practical information.

So, my questions are:

- is this action ethical?
- is this action acceptable?
- does this action indeed add to the quality of solution of the problem in question (e.g for some unknown (probably, but not neccessary, non SO user) surfer who stumbles upon it searching for the solution)?

Comment: Yes, yes, possibly, no idea

Answer (score 5):

Yes, what you did is fine generally speaking. Comments aren't supposed to last, so if there's useful information in one of them (either a comment on the question or on your answer), feel free to include it in your answer.

You could additionally link to that user's profile rather than just stating his/her name (since user names are not unique).

If you're worried about being accused or "rep-whoring", and what you quote from someone else is indeed significant, you *could* turn your post into a community wiki - you won't get rep from upvotes after you've done that. (Note: can only be undone by moderators, and I'd say do that if your answer is really a community effort. If it's only a minor addition, just enjoy the rep.)

<sub>As for this question here, it's fine too. Yes, you're probably over-reacting for that one, but it's a legitimate question.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

`Ethical`? 
Sure, you're giving credit to the original poster.

`Acceptable`? (In other words "Able to be agreed on")
I see that happen all the time, for completeness sake it's added in comments or other places in the post, so yeah, it's acceptable.

`Add to the quality of the solution`?
 Well... sort of. It doesn't really add to the over all Q&A (since that answer has already been posted). However if you are accepted there's always the chance that other users may find that post and only read your accepted answer, which now contains other valuable bits of information. So from that standpoint we can look at this as adding to the quality.

`overreacting`?
 Maybe a little bit. Unless anyone's called you out on it or downvoted you specifically for doing it.

IMO I don't think what you're describing is "wrong" or a "problem". I think it's fine. As long as your post **adds value**.

Comment: no, no one called nor downvoted, it bugged a bit me so I wanted to find out what other's think of it. thanks for the answer :)